# How to set RTL in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android

I search solution for me, but didn't find somethings for me.

This is my style, `TextInputLayout`:

```
<style name="MyWidget.TextInputLayout.StyleName" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yellow_my_mission_item_icon</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_input_layout_hint_inactive</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/text_input_layout_active</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
</style>
```

And for `EditText`:

```
<style name="MyWidget.EditText.StyleName">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
</style>
```

But on the screen it's seen like:
[image]

Comment: Check out link : 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182155
It may bug of support library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the Google link that Mavya Soni [shared](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182155), if you modify strings.xml with arabic text it will show correctly in RTL:

```
<string name="first_name">"الاسم الخاص"</string>
<string name="last_name">"اسم العائلة"</string>
```

Comment: Perfect, In English word will not display right, but arabic word will be display right side. Thanks :)

Comment: This method works well for the Perisan (Farsi), too.