# Android Error in Text_Input_Layout Edittext

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, apk

[image]

Does anyone know how I can change the position of the mentioned part of error floating label (as in the attached image) ? In the picture it is on the left but I want it to be on the right side of the edittext (because of my native language) . I tried gravity and layout gravity but none of them worked out . Thanks in advance .

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/numid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
app:errorEnabled="true"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/myerror"
android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.TextInputLayout"
style="@style/EditScreenTextInputLayoutStyle">

 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/tie"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:hint="@string/hint2"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    />
```

```
  <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
<item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint">#736f6e</item>
<item name="android:gravity">right</item>
```

```
<style name="EditScreenTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="colorControlNormal">#000</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">#000</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">#ff0000</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#ffff02</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint">#0000ff</item>
  </style>

<style name="myerror" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Share your layout file.

Comment: `android:supportsRtl` ????

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya. getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.Layout_Di‌​rection_RTL). How can I use it for edittext ?

Comment: @buzzingsilently. I put my layout.xml in the question . Please help me to show error from right to left. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Drawable err_indiactor = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.indicator_input_error);
    yourEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, err_indiactor, null);
```

this is the Drawable `indicator_input_error`

[image]

Comment: tnx . Do you know how I can put floating error label text to be shown from right to the left side of edittext ?@rafsanahmad007

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099639/how-to-set-rtl-in-textinputlayout

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for u

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText use, pass;

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        use = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edituse);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpas);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final String use1 = use.getText().toString();
                final String pass1 = pass.getText().toString();

                if (!use1.matches("") && !pass1.matches("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Succes",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    use.setError(null);
                    pass.setError(null);

                } else if (use1.matches("")) {
                    use.setError("This field can not be blank");
                } else if (pass1.matches("")) {
                    pass.setError("This field can not be blank");
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And the Xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_below="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edituse"/>
     <EditText 
        android:layout_below="@+id/edituse"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editpas"
         />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/click"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editpas"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps...and for English this works.For ur language its a right to left writing,then it may be the problem for the left alignment of the error msg.... ...Don't worry try this.

Comment: thank you but my question is totally about putting floating label to the right side because my language is written from right to the left .